# Change default company mode keybindings

Tags: key-bindings, company-mode, keymap

I think `company-mode` is a great package.
Though I would like to change some keybinding it has assigned by default.

For example, I would prefer not to use <kbd>M-n</kbd> and <kbd>M-p</kbd> in order to move in the different complete result list.
How can I change that?

Answer (score 9):

I read about [Change Minor Mode Keys](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/reclaim_keybindings.html) in the fantastic Xah Lee pages.
And I think I came with a solution.

I found two different keymaps in `company.el`: `company-active-map` and `company-search-map`.
So I redefined its default keybinding definitions that best suits my needs:

```
(define-key company-active-map (kbd "C-n") 'company-select-next)
(define-key company-active-map (kbd "C-p") 'company-select-previous)
(define-key company-search-map (kbd "C-n") 'company-select-next)
(define-key company-search-map (kbd "C-p") 'company-select-previous)
(define-key company-search-map (kbd "C-t") 'company-search-toggle-filtering)
```

That made it for me.

Comment: I wrapped this in `(with-eval-after-load 'company (define-key ...))` to defer `define-key` calls until company-mode is loaded; otherwise, the keymaps are not defined.

Comment: Mmm, I am not having that problem, but I am using `use-package`: https://github.com/tomasorti/myconf/blob/master/emacs/company.el#L14

Comment: Yes, your `use-package` call will have loaded company-mode. Another option is to `(require 'company)` if it's already installed (previous `use-package` call or installed manually). Otherwise, these keybindings must eval after load.